# Sample html page does not occupy the complete page . Remains only on on the top

Tags: html, css

below is the HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Framework Test Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">2 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-10">10 Columns</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">3 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-9">9 Columns</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">4 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-4">4 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-4">4 Columns</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">3 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-6">6 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-3">3 Columns</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css file is below.

```
* {
    border: 1px solid red !important;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.grid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
}
.row {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
}
.col-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
}
.col-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
}
.col-3 {
    width: 25%;
}
.col-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
}
.col-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
}
.col-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
.col-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
}
.col-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
}
.col-9 {
    width: 75%;
}
.col-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
}
.col-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
}
.col-12 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The Chrome web browser displays it as below.

[image]

Why is the bottom part of the page empty. I tried setting attributes 
max-height:100% to the grid class in css file but it did not make any difference.
I am using chrome browser Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)
and OS Ubuntu 16.04(64-bit).

Comment: are you using any css framework

Comment: Try height: 100vh; for the grid

Comment: I am not using any framework it's play HTML and linked CSS. I have tried with height as 100% the output is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your page to be always at least as high as the window, you have to add this CSS:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Note: I also added a background color to this rule below to show the actual size.

You could also add `height: 100%;` to `.grid`,  but I don't know if you really want that.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #eee;
}

* {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 8.33%;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 16.66%;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

.col-4 {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.col-5 {
  width: 41.66%;
}

.col-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-7 {
  width: 58.33%;
}

.col-8 {
  width: 66.66%;
}

.col-9 {
  width: 75%;
}

.col-10 {
  width: 83.33%;
}

.col-11 {
  width: 91.66%;
}

.col-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Framework Test Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">2 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-10">10 Columns</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">3 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-9">9 Columns</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">4 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-4">4 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-4">4 Columns</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">3 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-6">6 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-3">3 Columns</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

ADDED AFTER COMMENT:

A second example, this time with `height`settings for all classes. As you can see, these always depend on each element's parent's height, and they will become higher automatically if there is more content, so this isn't really useful in most real-world situations:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #eee;
}

* {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
}
.row > * {
height: 33.33%;
}
.col-1 {
  width: 8.33%;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 16.66%;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

.col-4 {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.col-5 {
  width: 41.66%;
}

.col-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-7 {
  width: 58.33%;
}

.col-8 {
  width: 66.66%;
}

.col-9 {
  width: 75%;
}

.col-10 {
  width: 83.33%;
}

.col-11 {
  width: 91.66%;
}

.col-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Framework Test Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">2 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-10">10 Columns</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">3 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-9">9 Columns</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">4 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-4">4 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-4">4 Columns</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">3 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-6">6 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-3">3 Columns</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Adding the height: 100% attribute to the html and body tag and .grid class did increase the body size and the border is at the bottom but the content inside the grid  i.e with class row remain as it is.

Comment: sure - your grid classes only have width settings, but no height settings, so they will simply adjust their height (which is default `auto`) to their content automatically. You could add height settings, but as soon as you add more content than fits in their, these won't make much sense anymore.

Comment: please note the second example/snippet I added.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}
* {
    border: 1px solid red !important;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.grid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
}
.row {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
}
.col-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
}
.col-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
}
.col-3 {
    width: 25%;
}
.col-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
}
.col-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
}
.col-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
.col-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
}
.col-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
}
.col-9 {
    width: 75%;
}
.col-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
}
.col-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
}
.col-12 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Framework Test Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">2 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-10">10 Columns</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">3 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-9">9 Columns</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">4 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-4">4 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-4">4 Columns</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">3 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-6">6 Columns</div>
      <div class="col-3">3 Columns</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The body height did increase but the div with class row are still at the top.